# PHP json_encode unread by jQuery AJAX Post

Tags: php, ajax, json, jquery

I'm posting from a form to a URL like so:

```
$.post('?class=articles&method=submit', $(this).serialize(), function(msg)
{
    alert(msg);
    $(msg.html).hide().insertBefore('#addCommentContainer').slideDown();
    $('#body').val('');
},'json');
```

And in the 'submit' method the last line is:

```
print json_encode( array('html'=>$content) );
```

Yet I'm not even getting to the alert portion in the jQuery.

I have a feeling it is because the 'submit' method is in a class file that is part of a template system (similar to phpBB). I know that creating a seperate .php file for submitting would work, but was curious if there was any other way.

Comment: what does the php file you are posting to look like?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you don't even have a specific url:

```
$.post('?class=articles&method=submit', $(this).serialize(), function(msg)
```

Should be I think

```
$.post('thePlaceIsubmitTo.php?class=articles&method=submit', $(this).serialize(), function(msg)
```

I believe that the serialize data will be appended to the url with and `&`, Be sure that `this` refers to the form tag

Answer (score 0):

try using the `$.ajax` method, instead of the shorthand. I believe the problem is that you're using the `POST` shortcut method, while specifying `GET` variables appended to the URL.

Let me know if this helps, if not, We'll be able to help you :-)

I'm on vacation, on a netbook, so I can't exactly write a whole new method at the moment.